# Implementing simple static access token security in Symfony

Tags: symfony

Just for the sake of learning, I want to create a very simple authentication example in Symfony without using any UserEntity. Is it possible?

I am very new with Symfony and I hope I do not get negative votes from here so please be kind. Can you please tell me what I need to do to make it work?

So far, this is my code:

security.yml

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        id: App\Security\UserProvider
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider

    donut:
        pattern: ^/donut
        access_token:
            token_handler: App\Security\AccessTokenHandler
            token_extractors:
                request_body

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

....

My controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DonutController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/donut', name: 'app_donut', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        return $this->json([
            'message'   => 'Hello there!',
            'user_identifier'  => $user->getUserIdentifier()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the access controller handler:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessToken\AccessTokenHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;

class AccessTokenHandler implements AccessTokenHandlerInterface
{
    public function getUserBadgeFrom(string $accessToken): UserBadge
    {
        return new UserBadge('abc@123.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself, what errors did you get and what was expected?

Answer (score 0):

The Security component of Symfony is quite User Entity centric.
Therefor i would say you need some kind of User to make it work.

You can create a dummy User entity or create a anonymous User object, implementing the UserInterface.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538413/541949

Slightly changed example from the above answer:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $apiToken = $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN');

    if (null === $apiToken) {
        // The token header was empty, authentication fails with HTTP Status
        // Code 401 "Unauthorized"
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('No API token provided');
    }

    // Check token is correct
    if ($apiToken === $this->expectedApiToken) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid API token');
    }

    // Use anonymous class which implements UserInterface.
    return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($apiToken, fn() => new class implements \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface {
        public function getRoles(): array { return ['ROLE_USER'];}
        public function eraseCredentials() {}
        public function getUserIdentifier(): string
        {
            return (string) Uuid::uuid4();
        }
    }));
}
```

The you also need to add the user to access_control:

```
  access_control:
    - { path: '^/donut', roles: ROLE_USER }
```